# Handling dynamic http requests instead of hardcoded http requests in Jmeter

Tags: automation, jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

I'm creating a 50 users load test on a JSF web application.

I record a scenario using JMeter proxy for one user who logs in, does some db operations and logs out. After recording the scenario, the recorded test contains http requests and data that particularly belongs to **the** user used while scenario recording.

At the time of running the test for 50 unique virtual users, the recorded test sends http requests and data which was in the recorded scenario. But in our application, the http requests and data vary depending upon the user. So how do I handle such situations in JMeter when it comes to methods being called depending upon the existence or non-existence of data for a user after logging in?
To be precise how would I make changes in my Test plan to manage dynamic urls and dynamic data for each virtual user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest versions of JMeter allow you to write the whole parameters (raw data) from scratch, so you could use variables in this field.

To achieve dynamic URLs use a Regular Expression Extractor (Post-Processor) on a prior request that define what request will be sent and use the variable in HTTP Request's path field.

If you know what request each type of users will send you could use If Controllers and test a thread variable, created by a previous Regular Expression Extractor, and inside each controller add the specific request.

If the subsequent request for each user is defined by the server, using redirection, just check "Follow Redirection" field.

See [JMeter Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter) for more examples on how to do this.